# How to make spring-boot application access different configurations for database for different scopes?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

This used to be the previous scenario.

```
@Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties("database")
  public DataSource database1DataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
  }
```

Now, to test SQL queries, I added this,

```
@Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties("testdatabase")
  public DataSource myperksTestDataSource() { 
    return  DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
  }
```

Similarly, I have created 2 methods each for `PlatformTransactionManager` and `SqlSessionFactory`. I realised that Spring-boot picks up `SqlSessionFactory` and if I create two there will be a conflict and there will be an `IllegalStateException` with Failed to load application context.

---

**Situation**:

I want to create two databases connection, one for production and another for integration testing. I have created configurations for each in `application.yml` file. I want spring to pick up appropriate configurations.

---

**What I tried**

I annotated production beans with `@Primary`. Which worked. I could get spring to run.

---

**Problem**

I do not use `SqlSessionFactory` directly, Spring does. If I mark `SqlSessionFactory` with primary and write another, it is of no use since no method is going to call it.

So, as a means of solution, I thought of conditionally assigning `SqlSessionFactory` with different datasources. But, how would I identify that the run time is a test.

Comment: You are making it overly complex... Just provide an `application.properties` and `application-test.properties` then when starting with `--spring.profiles.active=test` both files will be loaded. Or in short use Spring Profiles for this ...

Comment: @M.Deinum He doesn't even need that, just to provide different URLs at runtime.

Comment: ofcourse you can do that, but specifying all properties is generally overkill and you might want to have some defaults for, for instance your connection pool size, validations etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need any Java configuration at all. Cut it all and simply provide a value in the `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL` environment variable when you start your application; Boot will construct and wire a `DataSource` connected there.

Comment: Could you elaborate and provide references?

Comment: @TarunMaganti There is no elaboration. This is exactly the sort of problem Boot was built for. Just use the built-in autoconfiguration features in the standard way.

Comment: `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL`'s value  should be sent as a switch while running right?

Comment: @TarunMaganti Environment variable. You can also use `-Dspring.datasource.url`, but then that can leak credentials.

Answer (score 0):

simply create a application.yml with different profiles, like:

```
spring:
  profiles: dev

  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2DEV:mem;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    username: sa 
    password:
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver

spring:
  profiles: integ

  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2Integ:mem;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    username: sa 
    password:
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
```

Comment: This seems like a viable solution. How to give common properties separately?

Comment: This is giving me an error while running with common elements

Comment: This is invalid yml. Duplicate key isn't allowed